# Gatsby: set an image background through frontmatter, GraphQl and Styled-components

Tags: graphql, markdown, gatsby, styled-components, yaml-front-matter

I know this problem sounds a bit complex but it's not.
I'll try my best to explain it in a simple way:

- I'm making a list of blog posts for the homepage of my Gatsby website.
- The list is made of "boxes", every box that links to a post has a background-image.
- I pass this background-image to a styled-component, it gets the image from a **prop** value that I inserted in the main < div > element (you'll find the example bellow).
- **It works fine**, till I try use an image from my local folder under src (instead of using an online link that I simply putted on frontmatter).

---

Here's what I did in the past, and worked:
I put the url of the image on the frontmatter of the markdown file:

```
---
slug: "/post/my-post"
 [...]
imghero: "https:/path/to/image-online.jpg" 
---
```

Then query it with graphql:

```
const LISTING_QUERY = graphql`
        query BlogPostListing {
            allMarkdownRemark(limit: 10, sort: {
                order: DESC,
                fields: [frontmatter___date]
            }) {
            edges {
                node {
                excerpt
                frontmatter {
                    title
                    slug
                    date(formatString: "MMMM DD, YYYY")
                    imghero
                }
                }
            }
            }
        }
`
```

After that I insert the ***{node.frontmatter.imghero}*** it on a prop on the main div:

```
const Listing = () => (
    <StaticQuery 
        query={LISTING_QUERY} 
        render={({allMarkdownRemark}) => ( 
            allMarkdownRemark.edges.map(({node}) => (
                <Article img_background={node.frontmatter.imghero} key={node.frontmatter.slug}>
                [... etc ...]
                </Article>
            ))
        )}
    />
)

export default Listing
```

And finally I call that ***img_background*** prop in the styled-component:

```
const Article = styled.article`
    background-image: url(${props => props.img_background};);
    [... etc ...]
`
```

This method works.

---

Now I want to get the image from my "images" folder and not from a random url.

- I installed ***gatsby-remark-images***
- Set it on gatsby-config.js and put the path of some image on frontmatter.
- Test everything with http://localhost:8000/___graphql (and worked)
- Insert the additional query throught graphql:

  ```
  [...]
  frontmatter {
  date(formatString: "DD MMMM, YYYY")
  title
  imghero
  hero {
      childImageSharp{
          fluid(maxWidth: 630) {
              ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
          }
      }
  }
  [...]
  ```
- I modify the node on the component with the new path:

  ```
  <Article img_background={node.frontmatter.hero.childImageSharp.fluid} [...]> 
      [...] 
  </Article>
  ```
- Gatsby Develop compiles fine.

But then my homepage is completely white.
And the console of the browser says that *node.frontmatter.hero is "null"*.
I don't know that else to do.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a bit more info is necessary to resolve your issue, none of the thing you listed out looks wrong in itself. However so many folks got tripped off by image handling in gatsby that I'm writing a check list. It's meant to be generic, but I think no.5, 8, 9, 12 might help you locate the problem.

---

## Using image with `gatsby-transformer-remark` + `gatsby-transformer-sharp` troubleshooting

#### Setup

1. Is there any error at all? Sometimes gatsby will still compile successfully despite something's wrong. Check the console for anything that's... red.
2. Did you restart `gatsby` i.e turn it on and off again? Try removing cache & public folder (`.cache` and `public`) if you suspect something's wrong with them.
3. Did you list your image folder, or any of its parent folders in `gatsby-source-filesystem`?
4. In your frontmatter, is the path to the image *relative* to the markdown file itself? i.e path starts with a dot `./relative/path/to/image.png`
5. Does all markdown has a `hero` field in frontmatter? If a file doesn't have a hero field, it will be `null`.
6. If the image path in frontmatter is not relative or doesn't link to a file, it'll be treated as a regular string.

#### Query & Fragments

7. Does your query work? Test your query in http://localhost:8000/___graphql. Make sure the image field show up as a File node. Try something simple like

```
query {
  allMarkdownRemark {
    frontmatter {
      title
      hero {
        id
        name  <-- just enough to know the file exists
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If your `hero` shows up as a string, something's wrong, check the setup again.

8. Are you using fragments? Currently fragments can't be test in the graphiql tool, so you might need to find the definition of that fragment and test it manually. Here's a list of [the default ones that come with `gatsby-transformer-sharp`](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/master/packages/gatsby-transformer-sharp/src/fragments.js) and their definitions.
9. If you're using a custom fragment, make sure to define & export it somewhere.

#### Usage

10. If image doesn't show up in the browser, inspect & try to find what's shown up in place of your image.
11. Are you using `gatsby-image`? If so, make sure you're passing in something it can work with.
12. Make sure your image component receives what it should. If your component's expecting a path, don't pass in an object, like result of a fragment.

---

#### Some side note

- `gatsby-remark-images` only handle relative links in markdown image & html `<img>`, so if your image is living in frontmatter, it won't do anything.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer! I solved the problem, it was the no. 5!
  
Indeed the console on the browser talked about "null" problem.  

Do you know if there is any way to tell gatsby to just simple do not put any image if there is no hero in frontmatter?

Comment: Glad it helped! Sure, you can do that in at least 2 places: (1) Your styled component: `background: ${({ img }) => img || 'fallbackImage.png'}`; (b) Your template: `<div>{ node.frontmatter.img && <ImageComponent img={...}> }<div>`. 
 You can also modify `gatsby-node.js` or pass in a custom frontmatter parser, but that's probably too much

Comment: So it's possible to use a fallback image on a styled-component?  
`background-image: url(${props => props.img_background} || 'fallbackImage.png');`  

Should be good? I will try both because I think that the problem is not on the styled-component. Indeed with the first method (putting a simple image link on frontmatter) there was no problem and worked. The problem appears when I started to query some childImageSharp { ... } .  

PS: how should be the `gatsby-node.js` way?

Comment: I tried both methods you suggeted but unfortunately console keeps telling me that there is  
this is the first I tried: `background-image: url(${props => props.img_background || 'some-random-image-online.jpg'});
`  
and somehow the page renders but all the content of the box are white.  
This is the second method: `<Article {node.frontmatter.hero.childImageSharp && img_background=node.frontmatter.hero.childImageSharp.fluid.src }`  
also this gives me errors at compile time when launch gatsby develop.  
I will try to get some info for the `gatsby-node.js` option.

Comment: Hey @Santiago! Sorry, I thought you meant using fallback image, which is a little different ( was a little late in the day & I need more coffee ). You'd need to check if `node.frontmatter.hero` is `null` — if the field was missing, trying to access `childImageSharp` will throw error. Plus, it looks like your jsx syntax is a bit wrong -- you have to do nullcheck between element tags, like `<div>{ node.frontmatter.hero && <Article {img_background=...}> }</div>`. Feel free to make a new question, I'm sure a lot of folks over `react.js` tags can help you out!

Comment: Thank you so much! Don't worry for the later answer :)  
I didn't know that the condition have to be inside a `div`! Now it works! Although it seems too much boilerplate for a single prop (here's what I do: https://imgur.com/a/adAky1j ) . The only thing that changes is the `img_background` prop inside the article (it's called Article because its a styled-component for the `article` element). Anyway, it works well, and I also put a fallback image, in this way if the markdown file doesn't have neither `hero` or `imghero` property the box will have a custom fallback image.